# nodeJS agenda start job on a specific date

Tags: node.js, job-scheduling, agenda

Is there any way to start a job on a specific date using the `agenda` library?

This is how I'm creating the jobs:

```
const someData = {
  name: 'Name',
  value: 'Value'
}
const job = await agenda.create('daily alert', someData);
await job.repeatEvery('1 day').save() // specify when to start
```

But at this moment the job starts right after it was created, and I want to somehow specify the date when it should start, like tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

## Use agenda.schedule(`when`, `job`, `data`)

> Schedules a job to run name once at a given time. when can be a Date
>   or a String such as tomorrow at 5pm.
>   https://github.com/agenda/agenda#schedulewhen-name-data-cb

```js
agenda.define('send email report', {priority: 'high', concurrency: 10}, (job, done) => {
  const {to} = job.attrs.data;
  emailClient.send({
    to,
    from: 'example@example.com',
    subject: 'Email Report',
    body: '...'
  }, done);
});

(async function() {
  await agenda.start();
  await agenda.schedule('tomorrow at 5pm', 'send email report', {to: 'admin@example.com'});
})();
```

Comment: This only runs the job once, I still want it to repeat every x days.

Comment: Anyluck ? I also want to implement this every day at 12 pm

Comment: You can use
`agenda.every('day at 12pm')`

Agenda internally uses the package `human-interval` which parses the schedule format. More information in the documentation ->  https://github.com/agenda/agenda#creating-jobs

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you.

```
const scheduleAJobOnlyOnce = (options) => {
    let job = this.Agenda.create(options.jobName, options);
    job.schedule(options.start); // run at this time
    job.save(); 
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Define a "job", an arbitrary function that agenda can execute

```
const dt = new Date();

dt.setMinutes(dt.getMinutes()+60); // run after an hour

agenda.schedule(dt, 'hello'); // this will do it

agenda.start();
```